# SqlOpenHelper#onUpgrade(...) fails when database is opened as readable

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, sqliteopenhelper

I am writing a `ContentProvider` that uses an `SqlOpenHelper` to get its database.  I've just made some major changes to the database and so I put the version of the database up by one.

This happened:

```
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 2 to 3: /data/data/com.company.anothercompany.anotherothercompany/databases/twocompanies
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:262)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at com.somo.vertu.provider.FerrariVertuContentProvider.query(FerrariVertuContentProvider.java:94)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:56)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:42)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:255)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:55)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-13 15:36:15.668: E/AndroidRuntime(15917):     ... 4 more
```

I am calling `getReadableDatabase()` from the `query(...)` function because I'm reading, not writing.  In this case `onUpgrade()` would mean nothing is returned but I am handling that.  How can I trigger the upgrade on a writable database without just calling `getWritableDatabase(...)` in the `ContentProvider#onCreate()` method?  Or is that the best thing to do?

Comment: question is: are you using the same instance of `SqlOpenHelper` ... you should store `SqlOpenHelper` instance as a field in `ContentProvider` and then use it ... in `onUpgrade` you should use `SQLiteDatabase` provided by first parameter in this function ...

Answer (score 1):

**Rewrite**

You have three options that I see:

1. The easiest approach is to simply call `getWritableDatabase()`.
2. You can also store the last database version (perhaps in a SharedPreference file). Then check if the database needs to upgrade inside `getReadableDatabase()`, if so sneakily call `getWritableDatabase()` instead.
3. This is the most involved approach. It requires creating your own version of SQLiteOpenHelper that opens a writable version when an upgrade occurs...

Comment: Interesting idea, though I would then have to pass that information to the `ContentProvider`.  I think something like that might work though.  I'll think about it and let you know!

Comment: Actually could I override `getReadableDatabase()` to return `getWritableDatabase()` if the helper determines an upgrade is due?  I have no idea how I would pick that up within `getReadableDatabase()` though.

Comment: There isn't a direct way for your SQLOpenHelper to communicate with the one or more ContentProviders connected to it.  In the past I have simply called `getReadableDatabase()` every time the ContentProvider was queried. This way when I loaded a backup database in the background the ContentProvider wasn't left with a invalid database reference.